# Filtering Bluemix cloud foundry ERR logs on logstash

Tags: containers, logstash, ibm-cloud, elastic-stack, docker-container

I am currently working on setting up ELK stack on Bluemix containers. By following this [blog](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/07/08/making-logs-awesome-with-elasticsearch-and-docker/#config), I was able to create a logstash Drain and get all the Cloud Foundry logs from the Bluemix web app into logstash.

Is there a way to filter out logs based on log levels? I am trying to filter out ERR in logstash output and send them to Slack.

The following code is the filter configuration of the `logstash.conf` file:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424PRI}%{NONNEGINT:syslog5424_ver} +(?:%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog5424_ts}|-) +(?:%{HOSTNAME:syslog5424_host}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:syslog5424_app}|-) +(?:%{NOTSPACE:syslog5424_proc}|-) +(?:%{WORD:syslog5424_msgid}|-) +(?:%{SYSLOG5424SD:syslog5424_sd}|-|) +%{GREEDYDATA:syslog5424_msg}" }
    }
```

I am trying to add a Slack webhook to the `logstash.conf` output so that when a log level with ERR is detected, the error message is posted into the Slack channel.

My output conf file with the Slack HTTP post looks something like this code:

```
output {

 if [loglevel] == "ERR" {
        http {
            http_method => "post"
            url => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<id>"
            format => "json"
            mapping => {
                "channel" => "#logstash-staging"
                "username" => "pca_elk"
                "text" => "%{message}"
                "icon_emoji" => ":warning:"
            }
        }
    }

    elasticsearch { }
}
```

Sample Logs from cloud Foundry:

```
2016-05-25T13:14:51.269-0400[App/0]ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-05-25T13:14:51.269-0400[App/0]ERR npm ERR! npm owner ls pca-uiapi
2016-05-25T13:14:51.274-0400[App/0]ERR npm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-25T13:14:51.274-0400[App/0]ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-25T13:14:51.431-0400[API/1]OUT App instance exited with guid cc73db5d-   6e8c-4ff4-b20f-a69d7c2ba9f4 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"cc73db5d-6e8c-4ff4-b20f-a69d7c2ba9f4", "version"=>"f9fb3e09-f234-43d4-94b1-a337f8ad72ad", "instance"=>"9d7ad0585b824fa196a2a64e78df9eef", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1464196491}
2016-05-25T13:16:10.948-0400[DEA/50]OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid cc73db5d-6e8c-4ff4-b20f-a69d7c2ba9f4
2016-05-25T13:16:36.032-0400[App/0]OUT > pca-uiapi@1.0.0-build.306 start /home/vcap/app
2016-05-25T13:16:36.032-0400[App/0]OUT > node server.js
2016-05-25T13:16:36.032-0400[App/0]OUT
2016-05-25T13:16:37.188-0400[App/0]OUT PCA REST Service is listenning on port: 62067
2016-05-25T13:19:02.241-0400[App/0]ERR at Layer.handle_error (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
2016-05-25T13:19:02.241-0400[App/0]ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:125:7
2016-05-25T13:19:02.241-0400[App/0]ERR at Object.module.exports.log (/home/vcap/app/utils/Logger.js:35:25)
```

Is there a way to get this working? Is there a way to check the log level of each message? I am kinda stuck and was wondering if you could help me out.

In the Bluemix UI, the logs can be filtered based on the channel ERR or OUT. I could not figure how to do the same on logstash.

Thank you for looking into this problem.

Comment: You should provide a few relevant sample log lines.

Comment: @Val : I have added some of the logs above, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The `grok` provided in that article is meant to parse the syslog message coming on port 5000. After all syslog filters have run, your application log (i.e. the sample log lines you've shown in your question) are in the `@message` field.

So you need another grok in order to parse that message. So after the last `mutate` you can add this:

```
grok {
    match => {"@message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\[%{WORD:app}/%{NUMBER:num}\]%{WORD:loglevel} %{GREEDYDATA:log}"}
}
```

After this filter runs, you'll have a field named `loglevel` which will contain either `ERR` or `OUT` and in the former case will activate your `slack` output.

Comment: Do you need more info?

Comment: The issue that i am running into is, When logs are sent to logstash from the cloud foundry loggregator. I dont see a log level being passed. I only see a blank space where Log levels are supposed to be present. For example. Notice the blank space btw - -.`133 <14>1 2016-05-27T20:49:00.83113+00:00 loggregator aa497970-3f76-45ee-8e43-d4ca79768480 [App/0] - - New relic Successfully Configured`. Because of this, i am unable to filter out ERR messages. Do you know why this occurs ?

Comment: The log line you're showing in your comment is not at all the same as the one you've shown in your question. So which is the real one?

Comment: The logs from bluemix app looks like :`2016-05-27T20:49:00.83113+00:00  [App/0] OUT New relic Successfully Configured`

Comment: The same logs from logstash looks like: `133 <14>1 2016-05-27T20:49:00.83113+00:00 loggregator aa497970-3f76-45ee-8e43-d4ca79768480 [App/0] - - New relic Successfully Configured`

Comment: Notice that the log message in logstash is missing the log level info. It only shows a black value in this case `- -` . Am i doing something wrong here or is this how loggregator sends out messages ? Is there a way to get log level (channels) from CF bluemix logs into logstash ?